# Cobol pass function / lang features

Tags: cobol

Does COBOL support sending a function by reference to a function as a parameter?

I've only looked at a few tutorials at this stage. And Just trying to get an idea of what can be achieve easily. I.E. what knowledge that can be transferred over from other languages.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add more questions but keep the Stackoverflow Q+A style - one question (commonly with a note of "where did you look before, what did you tried, what do you want to achieve"), one answer.

I've answered the first one...

Comment: You may want to check the [latest COBOL draft](https://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=19468956) (currently 202x) to read more about this topic.

Comment: @SimonSobisch I'm happen with just the answer to the first question. I've only read tutorials about the language and heard there was a major skill shortage for COBOL. So I just wanted to get an idea of what can be easily achieved with the language. E.G. can a reactive library be built in COBOL to minimize over-updating state, and for that to happen certain language features need to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does COBOL support sending a function by reference to a function as a parameter?

"Yes".

```
77 FUNC-PTR  USAGE FUNCTION-POINTER.
SET FUNC-PTR TO ADDRESS OF FUNCTION SOME-FUNC
```

The reason for setting that into quotes:

- `USAGE FUNCTION-POINTER` was introduced in COBOL 2014, so it may not be available with a specific implementation of the language
- What many other programming languages define as "function" is commonly seen as a PROGRAM in COBOL. You could consider this, too. COBOL 2002 added something that is relative commonly available (it existed as an extension before)

```
77 PROG-PTR  USAGE PROGRAM-POINTER.
SET PROG-PTR TO ADDRESS OF PROGRAM "MYPROG"
SET PROG-PTR TO ADDRESS OF ENTRY   "MYENTRY"
```